# Why does this update only work once?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
SqlCommand mcd = new SqlCommand("update Customer_Info set Name=@name,Gender=@gender,DateOfBirth=@DOB,EmailID=@email,Mob_No=@mob,Landline_No=@land,Address=@address,State=@state,City=@city,PinCode=@pincod,Last_Login=@logi  where UserName=@user1", con);

mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",TextBox1.Text);
mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender",gender);
mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB",TextBox2.Text);
mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email",TextBox3.Text);
mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mob", TextBox4.Text);
mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@land", TextBox5.Text);
mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", TextBox6.Text);
mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@state", TextBox7.Text);
mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@city", TextBox8.Text);
mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pincod", TextBox9.Text);
mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logi",datelog);
mcd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user1",lblUserName.Text.Trim());

int d = mcd.ExecuteNonQuery();

if (d > 0)
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('updated ....')</script>");
```

It's only updating my database once. When I try to update again, it's not taking the value. Why?

Comment: *it's not taking the value* what value? fire [SQL Profiler](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQRE1S_DX4M) and see what SQL are you actually running in to SQL Server

Answer (score 1):

If the database (.mdf/.sdf) is part of the solution it will be re-deployed (and overwite the modified database) every time you start the application from within Visual Studio.

Either try to update multiple times within the same debug session or do not redeploy the database every single time.

**EDIT**

To fix it if this is what is wrong:

Install the database on your PC instead of adding an mdf/sdf file to the solution.

This installed database will keep the data you added/modified across debug sessions.

Comment: can u be more specific .......i understand what u are saying ...but can u specify the solution  ...for that\

Comment: after loading all text box are getting empty valued......and the database is getting filled with sapce values

Comment: @SharangBhoite - Please add more information to your question. Based on these comments you probably mixed up the order of execution. Show us in what class the code you posted is located.